# Easy way to get a number +/- parts per million in R

Tags: r

I would like to determine a numeric range of an observation based on the known experimental error.

For instance, let's say I have the observed value of `790.77` with an experimental error of `10ppm` (i.e. +/-10/1e6). That means that the number is actually anywhere from 790.76-790.78. 
If the observed value is 1254.1, then the range would be 1254.0-1254.2. Likewise, if the observed value is 12.500, then the range is 12.499-12.501.

I've been trying to come up with a simple way to do this in R, but it is not so easy because of R's propensity to round off 0s (e.g. 12.500 becomes 12.5).

Any ideas?

Examples for 10ppm:

`790.77 => 790.76-790.78
1254.1 => 1254.0-1254.2
12.5 => 12.499-12.501
790153 => 790143-790163`

Comment: So the input is a numeric vector. What is the output? Character vector? Two vectors of min and max?

Comment: 2 membered numeric vector. foo(790.77,10) => c(790.76,790.78)

Comment: It's an interesting problem, if I'm correct shouldn't trailing zeros be only relevant in case of [printing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6669720/1655567) and have no impact on the calculation?

Comment: Trailing zeroes are not relevant, but they make the problem that much nastier in the case when the machine reads out 12.50000 and R converts that to 12.5 and then you want to find the range 12.499 - 12.501.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing how you'd do this in an automated fashion without explicitly counting digits (i.e. by treating the numbers as characters)

Comment: It seems that at some point before this, you should "know" the significant digits of a given observation. Can you store that number (signif dig) in another vector, another column in the data.frame, or as an attribute of the variable? From here, you'd need a custom function to find this attribute and adjust +/- accordingly.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm with @Konrad: how to know programmatically if the significant digits of the value stored in a variable are correct. I think it needs to be known from a previous calculation and stored. If not calculated previously (e.g., a user-entered number), make an additional argument: `foo(value, err, sigdig)` where `sigdig` defaults to an "obvious inference" unless the user specifies otherwise.

Comment: Why am I not parsing this properly? 10 ppm is 0.001% of the value, which for 790.77 means +/-0.79077 leading to 789.9792-791.5608.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Oh thank god, I'm not alone.

Comment: Cos if it's as I interpret, the solution is trivial: `x + (c(-1,1) * (x * (y / 10000)))` where `x` is the value and `y` is the ppm. But perhaps I have a different understanding of ppms...?

Comment: ...and I think the way to do what the question literally asks for would be something like `(m*x - 10) / m` and `(m*x + 10) / m` where `m <- 10 ^ (6 - floor(log10(x)) - 1)`.

Comment: If the issues is printing rather than storage: format(x, digits=n). n is the number of *significant figures* you want to display, not the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add this as an answer because it appears to generate your desired output, but I confess I don't quite follow the rationale...

```
x <- c(790.77,1254.1,12.5,790153)
m <- 10 ^ (6 - floor(log10(x)) - 1)

(m*x - 10) / m
(m*x + 10) / m
```

...where the `6` would change depending on whether you're doing parts per million or billion or whatever, I guess.