# 3.999999999 returns 4

Tags: r

When I try the following in R, it returns 4

```r
(i = 3.999999999)
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I was expecting it to return `3.999999999`. Can someone explain why is it happening, is it due to floating point error?

Also, in the RStudio IDE, the variable is shown to have value `3.999999999`, but 4 on the console.
[image]

Comment: To output the value to the screen the value is rounded. Please try `print(4-i)`

Comment: Run in the console `options(digits = 10)` and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing R From Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669681/preventing-r-from-rounding)